# import image dynamically from JSON file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How can I import images dynamically so that each project page will load different images depends on project id? Is there a way I can pass image data url (in data.json) to images array (in ProjectItem.js) - currently i'm using static path so same images load on all single project page, please see below images for ref.

**ProjectItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
// import images from '../../data.json';
import './ProjectItem.scss';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotFoundPage from '../../Pages/NotFoundPage';
// import SingleProj from './SingleProj/SingleProj.js';

const ProjectItem = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  console.log(params.projectId);

  const images = [
    {"picture": "Images/Projects/Desktop/smx_sitemap.png",},
    {"picture2": "Images/Projects/Desktop/initial/home1.png",},
    {"picture3": "Images/Projects/Desktop/initial/home1.png",},
    {"picture4": "Images/Projects/Desktop/initial/home1.png",},
  ]

  const mainImageComponent = images.map((image)=>{
    return(
      <div key={image.id} >
        <img className="projectItemImg" src={'/' + image.picture} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
      </div>
    )
  });

  const imagesComponent = images.map((image)=>{
    return(
      <div key={image.id} >
        <ul className="project-item-imgs">
          <li>
            <img className="projectItemImg" src={'/' + image.picture2} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img className="projectItemImg" src={'/' + image.picture3} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  });

  return(
    <div className="container">
      <div className="projectItem">
      <p>{params.projectId}</p>
      {mainImageComponent}
      <p>The initial design - made in Sketch v. 52.5</p>
      { 
      images.length > 2 ? 
      imagesComponent : 
      <NotFoundPage />
      }
      <p>The final design - implemented in Wordpress 5.2</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  )
};

export default ProjectItem
```

**data.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "fitness",
        "category": "project management",
        "picture": "Images/Projects/Desktop/TeamK.png",
        "date": "2020-2021",
        "shortDescription": "",
        "url": "",
        "url2":"",
        "description": "",
        "desktop": [],
        "mobile": [],
        "resources": [
            {
              "name": "URL Parameters",
              "id": "url-parameters",
              "description": "URL parameters are parameters whose values are set dynamically in a page's URL. This allows a route to render the same component while passing that component the dynamic portion of the URL so it can change based off of it.",
              "url": "https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-url-parameters/"
            }
          ]
    },
    {   
        "id": 1,
        "title": "afterparty",
        "category": "ux / ui design",
        "picture": "Images/Projects/Desktop/JJEntertainment.jpg",
        "date": "Wed April 01 2020 11:39:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "shortDescription": "web design agency lead development and project management",
        "url": "",
        "url2": "",
        "description": "",
        "desktop": [],
        "mobile": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "sitemax",
        "category": "ux / ui design, frontend development",
        "picture": "Images/Projects/Desktop/Sitemax.png",
        "picture2": "Images/Projects/Desktop/smx_sitemap.png",
        "picture3": "Images/Projects/Desktop/initial/home1.png",
        "picture4":"",
        "picture5":"",
        "picture6":"",
        "picture7":"",
        "picture8":"",
        "date": "2018-2019",
        "shortDescription": "construction software company frontend development and web management",
        "url": "",
        "url2": "",
        "description": "",
        "desktop": [],
        "mobile": []
    },
]
```

**projects/:projectId**
[image: project single component1]
**projects/:projectId**
[image: project single component2]

It worked after I added extra map function for images, but this way I am not using `projectImages[0], projectImages[1]` properly. And this map function is really long and redundant. What are some of ways to shorten my code?

**updated code**

```
import React from 'react';
import images from '../../data.json';
import './ProjectItem.scss';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotFoundPage from '../../Pages/NotFoundPage';

const ProjectItem = () => {
  
  const params = useParams();

  const projectImages = images
  .filter((image) => image.title === params.projectId
  )

  const items = images
  .filter((image) => image.title === params.projectId);
  if (images.length === 0){
    return (<div>No such project</div>);
  }
  const projects = images
  .filter((image) => image.title === params.projectId);
  if (projects.length === 0){
   return (<div>No such project</div>);
  } else {
  }    
  return(
    <div className="container-m">
      <div className="container-l">
        <div className="projectItem">
        <p>project - {params.projectId}</p>
          {items
          .map((item)=>{
            return(
              <div key={item.id} >
                <img width="50" height="50" className="singleProjectImg" src={'/' + item.pictures[1]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        <p>The initial design - made in Sketch v. 52.5</p>
        {
        projects.map((el)=>{
          return(
            <div className="project-item-imgs gallery" key={el.id} >
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[2]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/> 
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[3]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[4]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[5]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[6]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[7]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[8]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[9]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <p>The final design - implemented in Wordpress 5.2</p>
        {projects.map((el)=>{
          return(
            <div className="project-item-imgs gallery" key={el.id} >
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[10]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/> 
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[11]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[12]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[13]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[14]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[15]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[16]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg" src={'/' + el.pictures[17]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/> 
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg" src={'/' + el.pictures[18]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {projects.map((el)=>{
          return(
            <div className="project-item-imgs gallery-s" key={el.id} >
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[19]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[20]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[21]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[22]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[23]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[24]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/> 
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <img className="projectItemsImg-s" src={'/' + el.pictures[25]} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'}/>
              </figure>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
};

export default ProjectItem
```

Comment: What build system are you using? `import images from '../../data.json'` (a commented out line in your code) ought to import the JSON data in most systems. Does it give you an error message? Did you `console.log(images)` to see what it imports?

Comment: Hi @edemaine console.log(images) works. It shows a full list of data in json file. I now want to achieve the following - for example on a page(component) called localhost:3000/projects/projectname1 only load image data that has a title projectname1in its array. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to filter the full set of images imported from your JSON file down to the subset of images that are just relevant to the project.  [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should do the trick here.  For example, to select the items from the full JSON `images` to those that have a `title` equal to `params.projectId`, you can do the following:

Here's some partial code:

```js
import images from '../../data.json';

const ProjectItem = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const projectImages = images
  .filter((image) => image.title === params.projectId);
```

However, it seems that you have multiple images listed within a single record in the JSON, with keys `picture`, `picture2`, etc.  You might consider turning that into an array of pictures, like the following JSON:

```json
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "sitemax",
        "category": "ux / ui design, frontend development",
        "pictures": [
            "Images/Projects/Desktop/Sitemax.png",
            "Images/Projects/Desktop/smx_sitemap.png",
            "Images/Projects/Desktop/initial/home1.png",
        ],
        "date": "2018-2019",
        "shortDescription": "construction software company frontend development and web management",
        "url": "",
        "url2": "",
        "description": "",
        "desktop": [],
        "mobile": []
    },
```

Then you could refer to the `pictures` array within the matching record.  For example:

```js
  // Find all JSON records with matching title
  const projects = images
  .filter((image) => image.title === params.projectId);
  // Abort/report error if no match
  if (projects.length === 0)
    return <div>No such project</div>;
  // Otherwise, assume just one match, and get its images.
  const projectImages = projects[0].images;
  // Now can use projectImages[0], projectImages[1],
  // or loop over them with projectImages.map(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! `console.log(projects)`outputs the project that matches `params.projectId`. In the last example you've shown, I added else condition after return line and included `const projectImages = projects[0].images;`  It doesn't return any error and word "projectImages" gets greyed out.

Comment: When I put `const projectImages = projects[0].images;` outside the filter function it returns "Identifier 'projectImages' has already been declared". Am I on the right track? @edemaine

Comment: It sounds like you have two definitions of `projectImages`. Make sure to use a different variable name for each `const` or `let` declaration.

Comment: I added updated code, I wasn't sure how to use `const` and `let` so I just used `const`. Updated code shows what I have got so far. Could you give me any advice?

Comment: Your updated code defines `projectItems`, `items`, and `projects` in exactly the same way. You only need one of those definitions. Each of them will be an array of size 1, though, because only one project matches the specified ID.  If you want to iterate over the *images*, you need to look at the first item (`projects[0]`), and then use the fields within. Look at the definition of `projectImages` in my answer, which is different from the `projectImages` you gave in the updated code.